# Is this Brownian Integral identity correct?

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, stochastic-integrals

$$\int_0^1 B_t dt=\lim_{\omega \to\infty}{1 \over {\omega}}{\int_0^{\omega}{Y_0+}X_t 
dt}$$ Where $B_t$ is simple brownian motion, and $X_t$ is a discrete random variable that can be 1 or -1 with equal probability. $X_t $ is the random variable given at t in the integral or summation. In other words $X_t=X_t$ wheras $X \not =X$. $Y_0$ is where the Brownian motion starts.

**Possible Proof:**

$$(1) \quad Y_{t+\epsilon}=Y_t+\epsilon \cdot X_t$$
As $\epsilon$ approaches 0 from the right the recurrance relation approaches $B_t$ and the area of $B_t$ is given by...
$$(2) \quad A_{T+\epsilon}=A_{T}+\epsilon \cdot Y_T$$
Solve (1) with $Y_0=C \, ...$
$$(3) \quad Y_t=B_t=\sum_{n=1}^{t}{\epsilon \cdot X_n}$$
we'll sub $\epsilon={1 \over {\omega}}$
$$(4) \quad Y_t=B_t=Y_0+{1 \over {\omega}}\sum_{n=1}^{t}{X_t}$$
Now we solve (2) in a very similar manner...
$$(5) \quad A_T={1 \over {\omega}}\sum_{m=1}^{T}{\left({1 \over {\omega}}\sum_{n=1}^{m}{(Y_0+X_n)}\right)}={1 \over {\omega^2}} \sum_{m=1}^{T} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{m}(Y_0+X_n) \right)$$
Where T is distinct from t. Here's the part I'm wondering about. Each inner summation will add $X_1$, every summation with $m \ge 2$ will add $X_2$, every summation with $m \ge 3$ will add $X_3$. So in general the nth $X_n$ will be added $(T-n+1)$ times. Also you can break $Y_0$ apart and sum it. This means you can rewrite the summation as...
$$(6) \quad A_T={1 \over {\omega^2}}\sum_{k=1}^T{(k \cdot Y_0+k \cdot X_k)}$$
This means this is just a sum of the integers. You can immediatly evaluate the $Y_0$ part. Instead lets write the integral. Using the definition of the definite integral...
$$\int_0^{1}{f(\omega \cdot x)dx}={1 \over {\omega}}\sum_{k=1}^{\omega}\left(f\left({k} \right)\right)$$
We are done. Have $f(k)=k \cdot Y_0 +k \cdot X_k$, let $T=\omega$, interchange the summation for integration, and let $\omega$ approach $\infty$.

Comment: How is $X_t$ supposed to depend on $t$?  And what is $Y_0$?

Comment: @NateEldredge $X_t $ is the random variable given at t in the summation. $Y_0$ is where the Brownian motion starts

Comment: I don't understand that definition of $X_t$.  I think a significant part of this problem would be to precisely define it.  The notation suggests that $X_t$ should be a different random variable for each $t$; how do you want them to be related to $B_t$?  Your notation $X_t = X_t$ and $X \ne X$ doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: @NateEldredge $X_t$ is discrete. It can only be 1 with probability 1/2 or -1 with probability 1/2. $X_3$ could be 1 or -1 but from then on, every reference to $X_3$ will be its initial value, whereas $X_4$ is in the "future" so we don't know its value yet. Basically the notation just allows there to be consistency when comparing random variables of the past.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't at all fit my understanding of probability theory, in which random variables are functions on a sample space.  In particular, the notion of "past" and "future" and things being known or unknown doesn't exist in the formal theory.  I think that in order to make your question precise you have to fit it into that formal framework, and as it stands I don't think that this has been done.

Comment: @NateEldredge I was afraid of that. Well, I'll try and formalize this later in a new question.

Comment: Another option would have been to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an acceptable proof method. I don't really see how that identity simplifies anything, but it is correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: One thing is sure, which is that does NOT "seem like an acceptable proof method."